# Iphone App crashes on AD HOC

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, cocos2d-iphone, adhoc

my app runs fine on development mode, but for some reason on ad hoc i get a crash right after loading screen.

I really can't understand what could be wrong, any tips on how to test it better?

Apple rejected it with this message:

We found that your app failed to launch on an iPhone 5 and iPad 3rd gen running iOS 6.1.3, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly. This may be because iOS 6 uses a watchdog timer for applications; if an application takes too long to complete its initial startup, the operating system terminates the application.

For information about the watchdog timer, please see Technical Q&A: Application does not crash when launched from debugger but crashes when launched by user..

Another possibility could be a missing entitlement. For more information, please see the Technical Note: Resolving "0x800003A", applications not launching and "missing entitlement".For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:

- include the complete details of your rejection issues
- prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.

For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.

If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Testing Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature".

log:

```
Incident Identifier: 594EE41B-0B8D-419A-B9B8-84CB58D1C174
CrashReporter Key:   bb741ef3c315eb6c114b0de36494c7de51511d89
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         tictactoe [85964]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F042F618-9077-4862-8938-ABADDC05E8B1/tictactoe.app/tictactoe
Identifier:      tictactoe
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-04-17 11:11:02.661 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN at 0x20b8f671
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   tictactoe                       0x00073708 -[CCBReader readFloat] (CCBReader.m:201)
1   tictactoe                       0x00075972 -[CCBReader readSequences] (CCBReader.m:959)
2   tictactoe                       0x00075bf8 -[CCBReader readFileWithCleanUp:actionManagers:] (CCBReader.m:1020)
3   tictactoe                       0x00075e9c +[CCBReader nodeGraphFromData:owner:parentSize:] (CCBReader.m:1061)
4   tictactoe                       0x0007605e +[CCBReader nodeGraphFromFile:owner:parentSize:] (CCBReader.m:1090)
5   tictactoe                       0x00076122 +[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:owner:parentSize:] (CCBReader.m:1105)
6   tictactoe                       0x000760f2 +[CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:owner:] (CCBReader.m:1100)
7   tictactoe                       0x000711f8 -[AppController application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:85)
8   UIKit                           0x34957a9c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
9   UIKit                           0x34957620 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1164
10  UIKit                           0x3494f82e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 694
11  UIKit                           0x348f7d1a -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1006
12  UIKit                           0x348f77a8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
13  UIKit                           0x348f71ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
14  GraphicsServices                0x3660e5f4 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
15  GraphicsServices                0x3660e222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
16  CoreFoundation                  0x32abd3e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
17  CoreFoundation                  0x32abd386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
18  CoreFoundation                  0x32abc20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
19  CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
20  CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
21  UIKit                           0x3494e468 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
22  UIKit                           0x3494b2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
23  tictactoe                       0x00070e1a main (main.m:14)
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x3ac06b1c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3acbd5d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3abf8d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3abf4374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3accdd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1bad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3accdd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1bad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3acbce30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3acbcfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32abd2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32abc02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x38a2e390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac260de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac25fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3accdd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1bad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3acbce30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3acbcfd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32abd2b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32abc02c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32a2f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x3337c888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x3340022c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac260de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac25fa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3accdd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1bad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3ac1b680 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0000000c    r1: 0x00000275      r2: 0x20b8f671      r3: 0x00000271
    r4: 0x1f570000    r5: 0x000eafc5      r6: 0x00000001      r7: 0x2fddd618
    r8: 0x3859ca59    r9: 0x00000003     r10: 0x3859cbdc     r11: 0x1f579bb0
    ip: 0x00073495    sp: 0x2fddd614      lr: 0x000736e5      pc: 0x00073708
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

.......

Comment: Have you tried Apple's suggestions?

Comment: I did, the app loads really fast ( so i doubt its the watchdog ) and my bundle id seams okidoki

Comment: Delete application from your device and then reinstall it. Does app run well then?

Comment: i'm going to offer a dinner to this sir: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/18183?r=22190

the problem is fixed now :)

Comment: OMG this CCReader code looks like a terrible hack. Why on earth would it need to memcpy a single float value?

Comment: No clue, but it did fixed my problem, im going to try and see if there is a newer version of ccbreader that also works, if there is i will delete this one :)